# Clarify my understanding of a bit of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working through a book that is all about functional javascript. In that book, there is the following bit of code:

```js
const forEachObj = (obj,fn) =>{
    for(let prop in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            fn(prop,obj[prop]);
        }
    }
};
```

I understand this as going through each property of an object then asking IF that object has that property then running a provided function.

What I don't understand is how the if does anything. Won't it always be true? Isn't it just asking if the `prop` it got from `obj` is a property of the `obj`?

Comment: The if is checking if the property is this objects prop or an inherited prop.

Comment: The `for ... in` loop will include properties inherited from the prototype chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

Lots of properties (`toString`, for example) are inherited but likely not something you would want to iterate over when checking keys defined on an object.

Answer (score 0):

This [`obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is asking if `prop` belongs to the Object itself and is not an inherited property.

Answer (score 0):

The `for...in` operator operates over all the properties in an object's prototype chain - `hasOwnProperty()` checks if that object itself has the property, and it's not inherited. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> unlike the in operator, this method does not check for a property in the object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answers already posted, getting all the propeties of an object and then filtering using `hasOwnProperty()` is equivalent to using `Object.entries()` to get a list of all the enumerable own properties of an object. All properties which are not inherited from its ancestors.

You can also do the same using `Object.keys()`.

```js
const forEachObj1 = (obj, fn) => {
    for (let prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            fn(prop, obj[prop]);
        }
    }
};

const forEachObj2 = (obj, fn) => Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => fn(key, val));
const forEachObj3 = (obj, fn) => Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => fn(key, obj[key]));

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const func = (key, val) => console.log(key, val);

forEachObj1(obj, func);
forEachObj2(obj, func);
forEachObj3(obj, func);
```